# how to fix valueError : invalid \x escape

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2uCt.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ard53.png)    def having_ip_address(url):
        match = re.search(
            '(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.'
            '([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\/)|'  # IPv4
            '((0x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\.(0x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\.(0x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\.(0x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2})\/)'  # IPv4 in hexadecimal
            '(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}', url)  # Ipv6
        if match:
            # print match.group()
            return -1
        else:
            # print 'No matching pattern found'
            return 1

```
def url_length(url):
    if len(url) < 54:
        return 1
    elif len(url) >= 54 | len(url) <= 75:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1


def shortening_service(url):
    match = re.search('bit\.ly|goo\.gl|shorte\.st|go2l\.ink|x\.co|ow\.ly|t\.co|tinyurl|tr\.im|is\.gd|cli\.gs|'
                      'yfrog\.com|migre\.me|ff\.im|tiny\.cc|url4\.eu|twit\.ac|su\.pr|twurl\.nl|snipurl\.com|'
                      'short\.to|BudURL\.com|ping\.fm|post\.ly|Just\.as|bkite\.com|snipr\.com|fic\.kr|loopt\.us|'
                      'doiop\.com|short\.ie|kl\.am|wp\.me|rubyurl\.com|om\.ly|to\.ly|bit\.do|t\.co|lnkd\.in|'
                      'db\.tt|qr\.ae|adf\.ly|goo\.gl|bitly\.com|cur\.lv|tinyurl\.com|ow\.ly|bit\.ly|ity\.im|'
                      'q\.gs|is\.gd|po\.st|bc\.vc|twitthis\.com|u\.to|j\.mp|buzurl\.com|cutt\.us|u\.bb|yourls\.org|'
                      'x\.co|prettylinkpro\.com|scrnch\.me|filoops\.info|vzturl\.com|qr\.net|1url\.com|tweez\.me|v\.gd|'
                      'tr\.im|link\.zip\.net',
                      url)
    if match:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1


def having_at_symbol(url):
    match = re.search('@', url)
    if match:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1


def double_slash_redirecting(url):
    # since the position starts from, we have given 6 and not 7 which is according to the document
    list = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('//', url)]
    if list[len(list) - 1] > 6:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1


def prefix_suffix(domain):
    match = re.search('-', domain)
    if match:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1


def having_sub_domain(url):
    # Here, instead of greater than 1 we will take greater than 3 since the greater than 1 conition is when www and
    # country domain dots are skipped
    # Accordingly other dots will increase by 1
    if having_ip_address(url) == -1:
        match = re.search(
            '(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.'
            '([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))|(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}:){7}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,4}',
            url)
        pos = match.end(0)
        url = url[pos:]
    list = [x.start(0) for x in re.finditer('\.', url)]
    if len(list) <= 3:
        return 1
    elif len(list) == 4:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

In python has an string escape for hex numbers (\xhh, Character with hex value hh).
If you have it, you change it.

Comment: you print me your output, please.

Comment: I have added screenshot of o/p error please have a look.

Comment: where did you put it? i cant see it.

Comment: you can see a link above as enter error description.

Comment: ... i need the output string. Please, print out the string.

Comment: i know the error, but i need you print out the wrong string.

Comment: Try to put in front of the string you pass this keyword 'r' having_ip_address(r"fd5f:c5e2:4ed6:0:f8de:1127:becf:c710"); and tell me

Comment: where should I exactly put this 'r' ?

Comment: I putted also an example above your comment.
Example: 
or r"your_string" or

x = "0xC0A83801"
having_ip_address(r""+x)

Comment: which python do you use? py2 or py3?

Comment: I am using py2.7

Comment: for me it works, what did you pass to your function?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAoFs.png)Try to use string literal `r` which tells python that it is a raw string (slashes are treated as characters not escape sequences).

```
>>> a = '\xAT' # is wrong
File "<stdin>", line
SyntaxError: (unicode error) truncated \xXX escape  

>>> a = r'\xAT' # is fine
>>> print(a)
\xat
```

Comment: @ShivamMishra what about your `url` variable? Can you show the whole error message